# How to return VM from many-to-many result?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to return from the GroupBook Class , A set of books they have same group id ...

I have this relation between those tables :

```
public class GroupBook
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Book_Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string User_Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Group_id { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }

    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }

    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }

}

 public partial class Group
{
    public Group()
    {

        GroupBooks = new HashSet<GroupBook>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Group_id { get; set; }

    [Required]

    public string Group_name { get; set; }

    public string Group_description { get; set; }

    public string UrlSlug { get; set; }

    public int state { get; set; }

    [Required]        
    public string User_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GroupBook> GroupBooks { get; set; }

}
```

also my book table :

```
public partial class Book
{
    public Book()
    {

        GroupBooks = new HashSet<GroupBook>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Book_id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string User_ID { get; set; }
    public string UrlSlug { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Book_name { get; set; }
    public string Book_Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GroupBook> GroupBooks { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my Vm:

```
public class GroupVm
{
      public List<Book> Book { set; get; }


}
```

I want to return in VM Set of books like this :

```
public ActionResult Index(int? Group_id)
    {            
        Vm=db.books.where(//What to add here to return set of books that == the group id I will send via method)
    }
```

As the previous example , I simply want to return set of books that exists with the same group_id , how to do that please ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `DbSet<GroupBook> GroupBooks` into your `DbContext`.

Then do something :

```
var vm = new GroupVm();
vm.Book = db.GroupBooks.Where(g => g.Group_id == Group_id).Select(g => g.Book).ToList();
```